# Regex to match a word but not another word

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex which matches a string if it starts with `http://www.xyzabc.com` but the string should not contain the word "getJobId".

For example:

```
http://www.xyzabc.com/abc          <--- should return true 
http://www.xyzabc.com/getJobId=9   <--- should return false
```

I tried with the following regex:

`^(http://www\.xyzabc\.com)((?!getJobId).)*$`

but it did not work. Could anyone suggest?

Comment: Double the backslashes, if what you've pasted is a Java string passed as a regex.

Answer (score 2):

I just took your code and ran it (removing redundant parens and anchors):

```
final String regex = "http://www\\.xyzabc\\.com((?!getJobId).)*";
System.out.println("http://www.xyzabc.com".matches(regex));
System.out.println("http://www.xyzabc.com/abc".matches(regex));
System.out.println("http://www.xyzabc.com/getJobId=9".matches(regex));
```

prints

```
true
true
false
```

Seems like exactly what you want, doesn't it?

### Update

In your edited answer you've got single backslashes instead of double ones.

Comment: you should explain about that regex string in your answer.

Comment: @Abu It is OP's regex, so it is fair to assume that he already understands it.

Answer (score 1):

A much better regex would be

`^(http://www.xyzabc.com)(?!.*?getJobId).*$`

`(?!.*?getJobId)` would check if getJobId exits and if it does then it would not match!

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `http://www\.xyzabc\.com((?!getJobId)\S)*(?=\s|$)`

`http://www\.xyzabc\.com` silded const

`((?!getJobId)\S)*` doesn't contain getJobId but able to have symbols

`(?=\s|$)` next symbol space or match is last word